# Chain rule for subdifferentials of nonconvex functions

Tags: reference-request, chain-rule, non-smooth-analysis

I have two functions: one of them $h\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathcal{S}$ is smooth, but not necessarily convex, and the other $g\colon\mathcal{S}\to\mathcal{S}$ is convex, non-expansive, and not differentiable. Also, $\mathcal{S}$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space with an inner product and I suppose that the composition $g\circ h:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathcal{S}$ is well-defined.

I will denote by $Dh(x)$ the derivative of $h$ at $x$. The B-subdifferential of $g$ at $x$ is the set $$\partial g(w)= \{W\in \mathcal{S}^* \ \colon \ \exists \{w_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{D}, \ w_k \to w, \ \nabla g(w_k)\to W\},$$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is the set in which $g$ is differentiable and $\nabla g(w_k)$ is the gradient of $g$ at $w_k$.

> Is there any kind of chain rule similar to this: $$\partial (g\circ h)(x) \subseteq \bigcup_{W\in \partial g(h(x))} W[Dh(x)]$$ without any additional hypotheses, in the literature?

I saw some papers dealing with nonsmooth chain rules for $g:\mathcal{S}\to \mathbb{R}$, for set-valued mappings, Banach spaces, Asplund spaces (all by Mordukhovich), for the case $h$ is affine, and for the case $g$ and $h$ are convex (I think it was by Rockafellar). The specific cases are not useful to me, but the general cases have too many hypotheses (qualification conditions). I would be happy with results concerning the Clarke subdifferential as well.

**EDIT:** I only want $\subset$ actually, I don't need $=$. Also, $W[Dh(x)]$ is an abuse of notation for illustration purposes.

Comment: Look at Theorem 2.3.10 (Chain Rule II) in Clarke's "Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis", basically $\partial (g \circ h) (x) = \partial g(h(x)) \circ Dh(x)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for pointing out this book! The result I was looking for is more similar to the corollary of Theorem 2.6.6, except that he deals with $\mathcal{S}=\mathbb{R}^m$ and I'm interested in the space of symmetric matrices. But I think this helps a lot. A LOT. Thanks again.